# Google spreadsheet API. Cannot specify axisPosition of a series

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to specify the axis of a series. If i specify targetAxis to be "RIGHT_AXIS", it doesn't work..

The Axis-titles for LEFT_AXIS and RIGHT_AXIS are also not showing. Only the bottom one.

I want the graph to look like this:

[image]

But it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Here the red axis is at the bottom, because this column contains much lower numbers then the column with the numbers for the blue bars.

Someone who knows how i can solve this?

Here is my code:

```
          {
            addChart: {
              chart: {
                spec: {
                  title: "Graf - tibber",
                  basicChart: {
                    chartType: "COMBO",

                    axis: [

                      // X-AXIS
                      {
                        position: "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                        title: "TID",
                      },

                      // Y-AXIS LEFT
                      {
                        position: "LEFT_AXIS",
                        title: "FORBRUK(KWH)",
                       
                      },

                      // X-AXIS RIGHT
                      {
                        position: "RIGHT_AXIS",
                        title: "PRIS",
                      },
                      
                    ],
                    legendPosition: "BOTTOM_LEGEND",
                    
                    domains: [
                      {
                        domain: {
                          sourceRange: {
                            sources: [
                              {
                                sheetId: 0,
                                startRowIndex: 0,
                                endRowIndex: endIndex,
                                startColumnIndex: 0,
                                endColumnIndex: 1
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    
                
                    series: [
                      {
                        series: {
                          sourceRange: {
                            sources: [
                              {
                                sheetId: 0,
                                startRowIndex: 0,
                                endRowIndex: endIndex,
                                startColumnIndex: 5,
                                endColumnIndex: 6,
                              },
                            ],
                          },
                        },
                        targetAxis: "LEFT_AXIS",
                      },
                      {
                        series: {
                          sourceRange: {
                            sources: [
                              {
                                sheetId: 0,
                                startRowIndex: 0,
                                endRowIndex: endIndex,
                                startColumnIndex: 3,
                                endColumnIndex: 4,
                              },
                            ],
                          },
                        },
                        targetAxis: "RIGHT_AXIS",
                      }
                    ],
                    headerCount: 1,
                  },
                },
                position: {
                  newSheet: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Improved request

*Disclaimer, there is a bug in the API for the right hand axis, see end of answer*

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "addChart": {
        "chart": {
          "spec": {
            "title": "Graf - tibber",
            "basicChart": {
              "chartType": "COMBO",
              "legendPosition": "BOTTOM_LEGEND",
              "axis": [
                {
                  "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                  "title": "TID"
                },
                {
                  "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                  "title": "FORBRUK(KWH)"
                },
                {
                  "position": "RIGHT_AXIS",
                  "title": "PRIS"
                }
              ],
              "domains": [
                {
                  "domain": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 0,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 8,
                          "startColumnIndex": 0,
                          "endColumnIndex": 1
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "series": [
                {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 0,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 8,
                          "startColumnIndex": 1,
                          "endColumnIndex": 2
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS",
                  "type": "COLUMN"
                },
                {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 0,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 8,
                          "startColumnIndex": 2,
                          "endColumnIndex": 3
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "targetAxis": "RIGHT_AXIS",
                  "type": "LINE"
                }
              ],
              "headerCount": 1
            }
          },
          "position": {
            "newSheet": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the row and column indices I changed because I was working with some sample data. `"type": "COLUMN"` and `"type": "LINE"` entries in the series. In fact, for me, I would get `400 bad request` without it. This produces a chart with `BOTTOM_AXIS` and `LEFT_AXIS` but not `RIGHT_AXIS` (see below for info on that). The chart also has two different scales so the line doesn't get overshadowed by the columns.

[image]

#### Right Axis

Unfortunately this is a current bug with the API: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153528225 - be sure to mark it with a ☆ to let Google know that this affects you.

#### Reference

- [Sample Chart Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts) - I used the sample to navigate the documentation to find out if there were any attributes missing.